# Optimizing utility and square root of divergence via SGD

Tags: reinforcement-learning, optimization

I am trying to optimize a objective for learning-to-rank, which tries to max(min) the utility(risk) of a ranking function with logged user feedback data. The idea is to learn a ranking policy which can generate rankings with max. utility (min. risk). The objective function looks like the following[image].

The regularization term is the chi-square divergence between the new policy and the behavior policy (used to generate log interactions), and it looks like this:[image]

I am trying to optimize this directly using SGD, and I am doing so by computing the gradient of this function, but the results are not what I expect. The performance of the policy after optimizing the regularized utility(risk) is the same as optimizing for the utility(risk) alone.

Any suggestions to something obvious that I am missing from this?